# An auto redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html

Some pages on my site and I would like to put javascript so that the user navigates for 5 minutes from one quick page to another, he will always be directed to another page.

is it possible for me to do this in java that leads to another page?

Grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval as below

```js
setInterval(() => {
  // logic for redirect
}, 1000 *60 *5);
```

Comment: I don't want to make a function that if the user keeps refreshing the page in 3 to 5 minutes it automatically directs to another page

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `window.location.href` to redirect another page:

```
setInterval(() => {
  window.location.href = 'your url';
}, 1000 *60 *5);
```

Comment: I used it but it doesn't direct, will it not take a lot of time to do it in second?

Comment: it's made the targeting but I want a function that only directs to another page if the user stays updates the page second then takes him off the page automatically to another page